# Multiple inheritance simulation in PHP, how to optimize the code

Tags: php, class, multiple-inheritance, extend

I have two classes A and B. Class C may be extends A and B. I need to do it optimally.

```
 class  A { 
    public function testA() { 
      echo "this is function testA \n";
    }
 } 

 class  B { 
    public function testB() { 
       echo "this is function testB \n";
    } 
 }

class C extends A {
   public  function __call($method, $args){
      $this->b =new B();
      try {
         return !method_exists ($this->b , $method ) || !$this->b->$method($args[0]);
      } catch(Exception $e) {
          echo "error";
      }
   }  
}

$object = new C();
$object->testA();
$object->testB();
$object->testD();
```

How I can optimize this code?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"? What's your actual problem?

Comment: You cannot extend class from both `A` and `B`. PHP doesn't support multiple inheritance

Comment: I know that  php doesn't support multiple inheritance.   t.heintz I mean how do I change the code so that it worked faster,using fewer resources.

Comment: He needs to simulate multiple inheritance optimally

Comment: yes, and I need to change only class c.

Comment: What do you know about traits?

Comment: I know about traits, but I cannot use here

Comment: Just replace `class` with `interface` in `A` and `B` definitions and replace `extends` with `implements` in `C` definition. And then you don't need to use `__call` method

Comment: he doesn't need to alter classes A and B?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple "inheritance" in PHP is handled by Traits, which are available as of 5.4.0
More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

```
trait  A { 
    public function testA() { 
      echo "this is function testA \n";
    }
 } 

 trait  B { 
    public function testB() { 
       echo "this is function testB \n";
    } 
 }

class C {
    use A, B;
    public  function __call($method, $args){
        // Called method does not exists.
    }  
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I cann't change class A and class B. I can modified only class C

Comment: So pass Instances of class A and B as parameters of C's constructor and call methods on these instances thru `__call` magic method.